# Byte compile setup

Tags: byte-compilation

What byte compile setup can I use when writing my init files?

Have been doing `M-x byte-compile-file` directly.  Would like to do a function that calls `byte-compile-file` on the current buffer.

Answer (score 1):

For an initial compilation I would either <kbd>M-x</kbd> `byte-compile-file` <kbd>M-n</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>, or else use <kbd>B</kbd> in `dired`.<sup>1</sup>

For automatically maintaining the `.elc` file thereafter, I highly recommend using the `auto-compile` package:

https://github.com/emacscollective/auto-compile

---

<sup>1</sup> More usually <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> -- refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(dired-x)Optional Installation Dired Jump`